# Provide external hive metastore while creating HDInsight spark 4.0 cluster from Command line using az

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm quite new to Azure. I'm trying to create a HDInsight Spark 4.0 cluster using powershell. Instead of using Azure Resource Manager module, I'm trying to do it using "az" command. Is there a way I can provide External Hive Metastore details while creating the cluster using az? When I try from the azure portal, I see that it is asking for Hive/Oozie metastore details. But I cannot find an option to provide the same while creating the cluster from the Command line (az).

There already is an Azure SQL Server and Database created and I'm able to create the HDInsight cluster by providing the server details. But where do I provide these details in the command line?